# CSS Selectors - Something is just not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, newsletter

Attempting to style a form using CSS, there are no styles applied to this item, currently I have gotten:

```
#newsletter_subscribe.button {background-color:#e10707;}
```

This works as expected and perfectly in Firefox & IE however fails to work in Chrome & Edge - I have thrown in the !important tag incase it helped but did not.

The raw PHP from the Woocommerce Newsletter Plugin is:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="newsletter_subscribe" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subscribe', 'wc_subscribe_to_newsletter' ); ?>" />
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome for me. Can you reproduce the issue in a Stack Snippet for us?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML for the input. Do you see the style when you inspect the element maybe striked out.

Comment: Well.... This is quite frankly embarrassing! I should have cleared the cache rather than just refreshing the browser!

The code works fine, thank you for the replies, I do appreciate it!

I don't know whether to laugh or cry about this....after spending 4 hours at it!

Answer (score 0):

Well.... This is quite frankly embarrassing! I should have cleared the cache rather than just refreshing the browser! The code works fine, thank you for the replies.

To anybody else coming from google trying to style the Woocommerce Newsletter Subscription Widget (I couldn't find anything anywhere else!),

The code you need to add into your Custom CSS for the button is:

```
#newsletter_subscribe.button {background-color:#e10707;}
```

Add any other value you would like the property to have of course,

The code to change the email address field is:

```
#newsletter_email { background-color:#feffff;}
```

And the code for the error message is:

```
.woocommerce_error {color:rgba(166,66,66,1);}
```

Thanks for all the replies guys!